# Why aws cli is executing old docker image when run from gitlab ci?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, gitlab, dockerhub

I'm pushing my docker image to my private docker hub account and then I run aws cli to start an instance from the docker image. However, aws cli always executes the previous version of the image, not the most up-to-date one. So in order to execute the most up-to-date I need to manually re-deploy or even restart the instance sometimes. I checked that aws cli starts 45 seconds after docker hub image is updated in docker hub. Then just as a test I added `sleep 300` seconds `before_script` in gitlab yaml file in the deploy stage before I run aws cli.

It seems like there's some kind of cache in Elastic beanstalk which is not updating the environment properly.
Has anyone ever run into such issue?

This is my gitlab yaml config in my subproject:

```
.build-docker-image:
  image: docker:18
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - echo branch $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME tag $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    - docker build .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE"
  except:
    variables:
      - $SKIP_BUILD == "1"

docker-build-staging:
  extends: .build-docker-image
  environment:
    name: subprojectname
  only:
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "staging"
  variables:
    CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE: myproject/subproject:staging

amazon_beanstalk_staging:
  extends: .amazon_beanstalk
  environment:
    name: subprojectname
    url: 'https://subprojectname.com'
  variables:
    AWS_VERSION: $STAGING_AWS_VERSION_BETA
    AWS_ENV_NAME: $STAGING_AWS_ENV_BETA
  only:
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "staging"
```

and this is the gitlab yaml in the root folder which contains all subprojects:

```
image: node

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

# sleep 300 seconds in order to prevent aws running old docker image
.amazon_beanstalk:
  stage: deploy
  image: garland/aws-cli-docker:latest
  before_script:
    - sleep 300
  script:
    - sh -c  "aws configure set region '$AWS_REGION' && aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --environment-name '$AWS_ENV_NAME' --version-label '$AWS_VERSION'"

include:
  - local: 'pathToMySubproject/.gitlab-ci.yml'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(updated after comment from @hitchhiker): For clear troubleshooting output, be sure CloudWatch Logs are enabled for your environment, and view the log for `ecs-agent.log` and you can see the PULL steps performed by the agent.   I was able to see very specific PULL steps when the environment was updated, or if the environment was restarted.

So sorry to hear you are still having problems.    Thank you for confirming you are running v2.   I did try to make guesses about your task setup and reproduce it. Upon running `update-environment`, the system automatically performed a PULL of my updated image, even if I used the exact same version-label.  Also, upon restarting the instance (from the Elastic Beanstalk console), a new image was pulled.

---

Original response:

If you are using a single container approach:

Inside your `Dockerrun.aws.json` file, please confirm you have "Update": "true" inside your "Image" section.  This instructs Elastic Beanstalk to always check your Docker Hub repository for new images.   If this setting is "false", then the Elastic Beanstalk service will prefer to use the previously downloaded image.

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/single-container-docker-configuration.html):

> When you specify an image in the `Dockerrun.aws.json` file, each
>   instance in your Elastic Beanstalk environment will run `docker pull` on
>   that image and run it. Optionally, include the Update key. The default
>   value is `true` and instructs Elastic Beanstalk to check the repository,
>   pull any updates to the image, and overwrite any cached images.

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Image": {
    "Name": "janedoe/image",
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "1234"
    }
  ],
  "Volumes": [
    {
      "HostDirectory": "/var/app/mydb",
      "ContainerDirectory": "/etc/mysql"
    }
  ],
  "Logging": "/var/log/nginx",
  "Entrypoint": "/app/bin/myapp",
  "Command": "--argument"
}
```

Please also note from the [ECS container definition documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_image), if you have old tasks running, they will not be automatically updated:

> When a new task starts, the Amazon ECS container agent pulls the
>   latest version of the specified image and tag for the container to
>   use. However, subsequent updates to a repository image are not
>   propagated to already running tasks.

Comment: I'm running `AWSEBDockerrunVersion` version 2 and I couldn't find any mention of `update` parameter in for the 2nd version (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/awseb-dg.pdf). I do make the command line call `aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment` though. Regarding your 2nd point I'm saying that when I **manually** run aws cli the updated image is not used.

Comment: While this answer doesn't provide a solution I'm awarding the bounty because you did take time to help.